# I can't pub get my flutter project with no reason

Tags: flutter-dependencies, flutter-pub, flutter-pubspec

I am learning flutter, and improving myself by doing different projects. But now, I've got one problem for hours. Why I can not pub get my pubspec.yaml file? I have Internet connection.But I can't get any package and can not pub get it.

I tried it in other projects without installing any package, but it was a fail too. How can I fix this problem? May be I have another serious mistakes. Please give me your advises and thank you in advance.

Comment: what the error message you got on console?

Comment: I searched Internet and did flutter clean, then kill all -9 dart. after that when I am trying to pub get it is loading a lot of time and never ends. In output it shows:   Waiting for another flutter command to release the startup lock...